# C# Program won't proceed until key is pressed

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program that prints number in a loop, but when "X" is pressed the program should stop (in theory).

It isn't working until a button is pressed. When i hold any button it gets in a loop but the loop should start with the beggining.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        string[] k = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" };
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k[rnd.Next(1, 6)]);
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.X)
            {
                break; 
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Comment: then you dont want if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.X) which is waiting to see what character you are going to press..

Comment: So what i should do add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only read a key when there is one pressed:

```
//if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.X)
  if (Console.KeyAvailable && ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.X)
```